Deletion of a child in 1-many relationship causes SwiftData to crash
Deletion of a child in 1-many relationship causes SwiftData to crash
Here are the models
@Model
final class Plan: Codable {
    var todos: [Todo]
}

@Model
final class Todo: Codable {
  var summary: String
}

now the view is:
struct PlanView: View {
    @Query private var plans: [Plan]
    @Environment(\.modelContext) private var modelContext
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            ZStack {
                if let currentPlan = plans.first {
                    List(currentPlan.todos) { todo in
                        Section {
                            Text("\(todo.summary)")    // <--- EXEC crash
                         }
                    }
                }
             }
         }
     }

and whenever I do a deletion like this it crashes:
struct TodoListView: View {
    @Environment(\.modelContext) private var modelContext
    @Query private var todos: [Todo]

    var body: some View {
          ...
    }

    private func deleteItems(offsets: IndexSet) {
        withAnimation {
            for index in offsets {
                modelContext.delete(todos[index])
            }
        }
    }


You're missing @Relationship in the model

In addition to the missing @Relationship, do not use Codable for your @Model final class .... unless you implement yourself
the required init(from decoder: Decoder) and  func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws .

You should've used like this.
@Model
final class Plan: Codable {
   @Relationship(deleteRule: .nullify) var todos: [Todo]
}

That solves the problem because setting nullify an entity in your plan model, it leaves your todo entity intact in your data store.
